# Find rotation angle to align vector with other vector

Tags: vectors, angle

First of all, sorry if anything is unclear or this is a dumb question, but I've been working on this a bit too long and can't find a solution.

I have two vectors pointing in different directions: Vector A and vector B. My goal is to rotate A so that it matches the direction of B, and I want to apply that rotation with an angle.
A and B are Vector3, but they both have a z component of 0.

I tried using $\operatorname{acos}(\frac{A\cdot B}{\|A\|  \|B\|})$, and that does give me a correct angle, but the sign is not always right. It gives me the same angle when B is 45° to the right of A as when B is 45° to the left of A.

Comment: The fact that you don't always get the right sign of the angle is "obvious" if you consider the fact that your approach necessarily gives identical answers regardless of whether you want to move $A$ to $B$ or the other way around, even though those two queries clearly should yield opposite signs.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to set up the matrix transformation for the rotation (from A to B).
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\
b_2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
We can re-write the inverse equations -- for going from components and solving for angles:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & -a_2\\
a_1 & a_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\
b_2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
If you solve this system, you will find unique values for $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$, which you can solve to give you unique angle.

The cosine alone is not enough to give the correct sign.